# Gerenciamento de vetores na memória do programa em Java

Tags: java, array, memória

Boa tarde galera, estou com uma dificuldade em alguns pontos em um desafio da faculdade. Bem, a ideia é fazer com que eu adicione e remova elementos de uma lista estática, porem de forma que eu aumente e diminua o tamanho dela (resumidamente fazer a variável apontar para outro vetor de tamanho diferente), mas foi ai que achei o problema, fico preocupado com o consumo de memória com o tempo, se caso adicione e remova muuitos elementos, não consigo pensar em uma forma de otimizar bem essa memória.

Comment: Se vai criar outro array, basta descartar o anterior, que o garbage collector se encarrega de limpá-lo da memória. Aliás, a ideia de usar Java (e qualquer outra linguagem com gerenciamento automático de memória) é justamente não ter que se preocupar com isso (na verdade as preocupações são diferentes, mas não vem ao caso).

Answer (score -2):

acredito que vc nao precisa se preocupar com isso agora, o garbage collector do java pode cuidar da memoria para voce. Da uma pesquisada sobre isso, mas talvez se esse vetor precisar armazenar uma grande quantidade de dados, talvez voce precise mesmo ve uma forma de otimizar esse gerenciamento de memória